# An error occurred (ResourceInUseException) when calling the CreateTable operation: Table already exists:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, python-3.6

Getting below error while creating a table in dynamodb to put data from s3 bucket and load into the table having more than 4-columns.

error in cloudwatchlogs:"module initialization error: An error occurred (ResourceInUseException) when calling the CreateTable operation: Table already exists: "
sample code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def txt_reader(event,context):
bucket_path = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key_path = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket_path,Key = key_path)
body_rows = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')

# Create the DynamoDB table.
   table_name = dynamodb.create_table(
   TableName='TFM',
     KeySchema=[
      {
        'AttributeName': 'CN',
        'KeyType': 'HASH'
       },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'SN',
        'KeyType': 'RANGE'
    }
],
AttributeDefinitions=[
    {
        'AttributeName': 'CN',
        'AttributeType': 'S'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'SN',
        'AttributeType': 'S'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'WF',
        'AttributeType': 'S'
    },
],
#defining local secondary index on column WF
LocalSecondaryIndexes=[
           {
              'IndexName': 'WF',
              'KeySchema': [
                  {
                    'KeyType': 'HASH',
                    'AttributeName': 'CN'
                },
                {
                    'KeyType': 'RANGE',
                    'AttributeName': 'WF'
                }
            ],

            'Projection': {
                'ProjectionType': 'ALL',
            }
        }
    ],
ProvisionedThroughput={
    'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
}
)

table=dynamodb.Table(table_name)

#using a method batch_writer as batch below

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for row in body_rows:
        batch.put_item(Item = {
            'CN':row.split('|')[0],
            'SN':row.split('|')[1],
            'WF':row.split('|')[2],
            'sf':row.split('|')[3],
            'Con':row.split('|')[4],
            'LCI':row.split('|')[5]
            })
```

MY Queries: Please help me by taking some random '|' seperated values for the given columns in a txt file and run the code in lambda.

Note: Services to be used are Dynamodb as a resource, S3 as a Client. In this case, i am getting the error but i can see, everytime i save the code and upload the txt file in s3, table is getting created also and then having this above given error. I delete the table, save the lambda code and upload the file in S3 and again the same error i get. Here S3 is acting as a trigger. I have created one S3-lambda-cloudwatchlogs-dynamodb role also.

already given above

Answer (score 0):

Normally, table create is one time operation in most cases. You should create table in another script, have it run once and then run the other part of the code on lambda.

If anyways, you have to create and destroy table every time, then check the status of the table prior to put_item operation. Because once you execute table create API, if not be created instantaneously. Its a request to create table, which will take a while to create. Here is the doc describing table_status, based on which can take decision when you should run put_item operation

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.table_status